# Deleting data during the run Android apps

Tags: android

The app tries to delete the data from the test case .
I tried the following code:

```
    ## Clear App data ##    

    public void clearApplicationData() {

    File cache = getCacheDir();
    try {

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());

    if (appDir.exists()) {
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for (String s : children) {
            if (!s.equals("lib") && 
               !(s.equals("shared_prefs"))) 
            {
                deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
            }
        }
    }
```

When you run this code, only app data is first deleted.
However, if you delete an app, data without quitting the app is not deleted.

```
    public void deleteFiles(String pkg) {

    File file = new File(pkg);
    DeleteRecursive(file);

    if (file.exists()) {

        String deleteCmd = "rm -r " + pkg;

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            runtime.exec(deleteCmd);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }




public class MainActivity extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<activitys.appcro.finalnmc.activitys.WebMainActivity> {

      @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        //setUp() is run before a test case is started.
        //This is where the saodlfmf7298
        // olo object is created.
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
        this.solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }
    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        //tearDown() is run after a test case has finished.
        //finishOpenedActivities() will finish all the activities that have been opened during the test execution.
        try {
            solo.finishOpenedActivities();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getActivity().finish();
        super.tearDown();
        Log.d("rightWeb", "tearDown");
    }

   public void test()
   {
        while(true)
       {
              int i = 0;
              testCase(i);
              clearApplicationData();
              i++;
       }
   }



}
```

so, It was carried out with changing the thread..

```
 getInstrumentation().runOnUiThread(new Runnable{clearApplicationData();});
```

The result is also the first time only initialization

and the second beginning was not initialized .

How can you clear the app's data from the test case